# Cannot access elements inside included layout: Android

Tags: android, xml, include

I have an xml file which contains a button and its called **button/xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Button" />
```

I have another layout called **login.xml**, which includes the button.xml in it twice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/loginUser1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        layout="@layout/button" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/loginUser2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            layout="@layout/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I try to access each of the buttons seperately in my Java class, I get an error while pointing to **loginUser1**. The error says **NullPointerException**. Since I know for sure that loginUser1 exists, why am I still getting the error?

```
    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loginUser1); //null pointer exception HERE!
    final Button button = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.loginButton1);
    button.setText("button one");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out your log cat. You should get `ClassCastException` instead of `NullPointerException`. The problem is that view with id `R.id.loginUser1` is actually a `Button` and not a `LinearLayout`. The following code should work well:

```
final Button first = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginUser1);
final Button second = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginUser2);

first.setText("button one");
second.setText("button two");
```

Also, please note that there is no button with id `R.id.loginButton1` anymore because its id was overridden by`include` tag

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

final Button first = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton1);
first.setText("your text");

as loginUser1 is a button and not a LinearLayout.

Comment: I am sorry but this only changes the text of the first button...how do you suggest I change the text for the second one?